# count rows with max value within group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
| ID  | CATEGORY | PRIORITY |
| --- | -------- | -------- |
| 1   | dogs     | 1        |
| 2   | dogs     | 2        |
| 3   | cats     | 1        |
| 4   | cats     | 2        |
| 5   | cats     | 2        |
```

What I want to get is a grouped resultset that looks like this:

```
| CATEGORY | HIGHEST_PRIORITY | NMB_ROWS_WITH_HIGHEST_PRIO |
| -------- | ---------------- | -------------------------- |
| dogs     | 2                | 1                          |
| cats     | 2                | 2                          |
```

I imagined a query in the following form  could work:

```
SELECT CATEGORY,
  MAX(PRIORITY),  -- Highest Priority of Category
  COUNT(MAX(PRIORITY)) -- Count how many rows within a category have the highest priority
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY;
```

but is not possible to count the number rows with `COUNT(MAX(PRIORITY))` within the group this way. Is there any way to achieve this without using subqueries?
(I use an Oracle 12c Database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window functions come in handy here.  We can first iterate the table once and generate the highest priority value for each category.  Then, aggregate and do a conditional count of the number of times that each priority equals that max priority.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        MAX(PRIORITY) OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY) MAX_PRIORITY
    FROM MY_TABLE t
)

SELECT
    CATEGORY,
    MAX(PRIORITY) AS HIGHEST_PRIORITY,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN PRIORITY = MAX_PRIORITY THEN 1 END) AS NMB_ROWS_WITH_HIGHEST_PRIO
FROM CTE
GROUP BY
    CATEGORY;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can simply using having Clause to achieve it
Simple sample

```
SELECT CATEGORY, MAX(PRIORITY) AS HIGHEST_PRIORITY, COUNT(MAX(PRIORITY)) AS NMB_ROWS_WITH_HIGHEST_PRIO 
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP BY CATEGORY 
HAVING MAX(PRIORITY) >1;
```

> Hope thats help you

Comment: The problem is that `COUNT(MAX(PRIORITY))` is an invalid expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select A.category,HIGHEST_PRIORITY,NMB_ROWS_WITH_HIGHEST_PRIO 
from
(
SELECT CATEGORY,MAX(PRIORITY) as HIGHEST_PRIORITY FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY
)A inner join 
(SELECT CATEGORY,PRIORITY,count(*) as NMB_ROWS_WITH_HIGHEST_PRIO FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY,PRIORITY
)B on A.CATEGORY=B.CATEGORY and A.HIGHEST_PRIORITY=B.PRIORITY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using window functions -

```
SELECT CATEGORY, PRIORITY, COUNT(PRIORITY)
FROM (SELECT CATEGORY
            ,PRIORITY
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY PRIORITY DESC) RN
      FROM MY_TABLE) X
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY CATEGORY, PRIORITY
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ca0a49e6837fedc1d8d1e3a44faeaf4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with aggregation:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, PRIORITY, CNT
FROM (SELECT CATEGORY, PRIORITY, COUNT(*) as CNT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MY_TABLE
      GROUP BY CATEGORY, PRIORITY
     ) cp
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mt.category, max(mt.priority), count(mt.priority)
from my_table mt
where priority = (select max(mt2.priority)
                  from my_table mt2
                  where mt1.category = mt2.category)
group by mt.category;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT `PRIORITY`, count(`PRIORITY`) as count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY PRIORITY
ORDER BY count desc
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [self-join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp) and [aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm).

```sql
SELECT t2.category        AS CATEGORY,
       Max(t1.priority)   AS HIGHEST_PRIORITY,
       Count(t2.priority) AS NMB_ROWS_WITH_HIGHEST_PRIO
FROM   (SELECT Max(priority) AS priority, category
        FROM   my_table
        GROUP  BY category) t1
       inner join my_table t2 ON t1.category = t2.category AND t1.priority = t2.priority
GROUP  BY t2.category
```